# Unable to load chrome extention with playwright for automation

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Hello guys I just started using playwright and JavaScript. I am having a trouble figuring out how to load chrome extension from local folder while opening browser for automation. I want to automate chrome extension but so far the only clue that I have got is to use this code

```html
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const pathToExtension = require('path').join(__dirname, 'my-extension');
  const userDataDir = '/tmp/test-user-data-dir';
  const browserContext = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir,{
    headless: false,
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
      `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`
    ]
  });
  const backgroundPage = browserContext.backgroundPages()[0];
  // Test the background page as you would any other page.
  await browserContext.close();
})();
```

which I am unable to understand that how this would be configured and in which file should I add this code. Can anybody help me in this regard please?

Comment: am in the same boat, please let me know if you found some solution. I cannot load my extension either and I have no clear resource, to understand the step by step process.

Comment: Is this helping you? https://playwright.dev/docs/chrome-extensions